# Sentry not getting errors from localhost (onpremise)

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, docker, sentry

Sentry is not picking up any errors from my django project.

I am setting up sentry using docker(onpremise) to track errors from my project.

I have sentry up and running on aws server and it looks running fine as I can send verification emails (smpt set up with sendgrid) and can add organisations, projects and etc.

My project uses django and I am trying to set up with unified sdk (sentry-sdk).
After setting up the client with DNS.

```
>>> from sentry_sdk import capture_message
>>> capture_message('test')
'07d8c4c1eb1f4b6bb5e0766d5078a9c4'
```

When I run the above code, I can't see anything on the sentry UI. Not even filtered errors.

I am very new to this so not sure what I am missing.
Should I configure logging??

Only thing sentry picks up now is, if there is an error occurred on the sentry docker container.

Comment: I added     debug=True    into sentry_sdk.init() and it's working now. 
https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/configuration/?platform=python#debug

A little weird as it's not mentioned on their document, and it should only adding debugging information to the event. Any idea or am I missing something???